# Error getting middle of android studio installation

Tags: android

I am trying to Install Android Studio 2.1.1 in my system but at the middle of installation getting some error like"Error opening file for writing". I have attached screen shot, please help me. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the other version. I doubt that will help but you never know. If not try to run the installer as admin

Comment: Did you try downloading the `x32` or `x64` version? Whichever is the opposite to what you originally downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Download latest version [**Here**](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

your copy is corrupted or some files are missing.